# How to Make Header and Horizontal Menu Consistent When Navigating Pages

Tags: css, iphone, html, phonegap-build

Mobile app developed with HTML5stack and sent through PhoneGap Build. Testing on iOS devices (4s & 5c). Noticed that when I click to navigate to a new page that my header and menu blank out between loads, giving a less than seamless appearance. I was hoping that by keeping header and menu in the exact location throughout all pages that it would look like the header and menu stayed in place while everything else changed. I'm guessing someone will tell me to use a structural framework like AngularJS, but I don't know it & cannot spare much more time on this steep learning curve I'm climbing. Perhaps the next project.

My CSS code below.

```
    #menu {
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

img.headerImg{
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 0%;       
    padding: 0px ;                  
    vertical-align: top;
}

.menu, .table {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0% ;
    padding: 0% ;
    color: white;
    background-color: #1E3B56;
    font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "sans-serif";
    font-size: x-small;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 20%; 
    border-top-left-radius: 5%;
}

.navImg {
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    align-items: center;
    position: absolute;     
    margin: 0px 4px 0px 0px;
    padding: 2px 2px 0px 0px;
}
```

Hopefully, there's a solution out there, but if I have to live with it, then I have to live with it ... for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by making the hybrid mobile app into a single page application and used jQuery Mobile data-role="page".

Though I was too far into my project to transfer my code into this template, I will likely next time use the below code as an SPA starter. This came from a really useful tutorial that I found on [Youtube from LinuxAcademy](https://youtu.be/JTNp0CkIZio)

Posting html starter template for you and the future me.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQyery Mobile - Fixed Header &amp; Footer</title>
<link rel="stylesheet"href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<!--<div data-role="page" data-fullscreen="true">  // to show a full page w/hiding header/footer disappears and reappears -->
<div data-role="page">
<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
<h1>I'm your header</h1>
<div data-role='navbar'><ul>
<li><a href="" data-icon="delete">Nav 01</a></li>
<li><a href="" data-icon="check" data-iconpos="bottom">Nav 02</a></li>              
</ul></div>
</div><!--  /end header -->
<div data-role="content">
<h1>I'm your content</h1>
<p>Dominus meus: tu es ergo habet. Lorem quod fecisti mihi carissimi. Vos have ut misereatur sunt incredibili obtulerunt ut vetustus amissus utitur salute mundi. Quia bonus es tu. Et misericordias tuas usque in aeternum manet! Dominus meus: tu es ergo habet. Lorem quod fecisti mihi carissimi. Vos have ut misereatur sunt incredibili obtulerunt ut vetustus amissus utitur salute mundi. Quia bonus es tu. Et misericordias tuas usque in aeternum manet! Dominus meus: tu es ergo habet. Lorem quod fecisti mihi carissimi. Vos have ut misereatur sunt incredibili obtulerunt ut vetustus amissus utitur salute mundi. Quia bonus es tu. Et misericordias tuas usque in aeternum manet! My Lord, You are so Wonderful. Thank you for all that you have done for me and my loved ones. You are incredibly gracious to have offered salvation to a lost world. You are good. And your mercies endureth forever! Dominus meus: tu es ergo habet. Lorem quod fecisti mihi carissimi. Vos have ut misereatur sunt incredibili obtulerunt ut vetustus amissus utitur salute mundi. Quia bonus es tu. Et misericordias tuas usque in aeternum manet! Dominus meus: tu es ergo habet. Lorem quod fecisti mihi carissimi. Vos have ut misereatur sunt incredibili obtulerunt ut vetustus amissus utitur salute mundi. Quia bonus es tu. Et misericordias tuas usque in aeternum manet! Dominus meus: tu es ergo habet. Lorem quod fecisti mihi carissimi. Vos have ut misereatur sunt incredibili obtulerunt ut vetustus amissus utitur salute mundi. Quia bonus es tu. Et misericordias tuas usque in aeternum manet! Dominus meus: tu es ergo habet. Lorem quod fecisti mihi carissimi. Vos have ut misereatur sunt incredibili obtulerunt ut vetustus amissus utitur salute mundi. Quia bonus es tu. Et misericordias tuas usque in aeternum manet! Dominus meus: tu es ergo habet. Lorem quod fecisti mihi carissimi. Vos have ut misereatur sunt incredibili obtulerunt ut vetustus amissus utitur salute mundi. Quia bonus es tu. Et misericordias tuas usque in aeternum manet! Dominus meus: tu es ergo habet. Lorem quod fecisti mihi carissimi. Vos have ut misereatur sunt incredibili obtulerunt ut vetustus amissus utitur salute mundi. Quia bonus es tu. Et misericordias tuas usque in aeternum manet! My Lord, You are so Wonderful. Thank you for all that you have done for me and my loved ones. You are incredibly gracious to have offered salvation to a lost world. You are good. And your mercies endureth forever! Dominus meus: tu es ergo habet. Lorem quod fecisti mihi carissimi. Vos have ut misereatur sunt incredibili obtulerunt ut vetustus amissus utitur salute mundi. Quia bonus es tu. Et misericordias tuas usque in aeternum manet! Dominus meus: tu es ergo habet. Lorem quod fecisti mihi carissimi. Vos have ut misereatur sunt incredibili obtulerunt ut vetustus amissus utitur salute mundi. Quia bonus es tu. Et misericordias tuas usque in aeternum manet! Dominus meus: tu es ergo habet. Lorem quod fecisti mihi carissimi. Vos have ut misereatur sunt incredibili obtulerunt ut vetustus amissus utitur salute mundi. Quia bonus es tu. Et misericordias tuas usque in aeternum manet!</p>  </div><!--  /end content -->
<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
<h1>I'm your footer</h1>
<div data-role='navbar'>
<ul>
<li><a href="" data-icon="star">Nav 03</a></li>
<li><a href="">Nav 04</a></li>              
</ul>
</div></div><!--  /end footer -->           
</div>
</body>
</html>
```